# Ejecutar función después de validación en un datatable

Tags: validación, datatable

tengo una función que valida los inputs de calificaciones en un datatable estas no puedas ser diferentes de cero y menores de 70. Si la calificación está fuera del rango arroja un alert y si lo está ejecuta una función que manda mi información a gaurdar. Pero a pesar de que la validación se ejecuta, siempre se ejecuta la función que envía la información, no sé como hacer que si la validación me retorna el false pare la ejecución y de caso contrario se ejecute la funcion enviar().

Comparto el código de la función.

```
function validaCalificacion(){
    var table = $('#tabla_calificaciones').DataTable();

    table.rows().every( function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        table.cells($(this), $('td')).every(function (rowIdx, colIdx){  
            let calif;
                    
            if(colIdx === 1){ 
                var node = this.node();
                noControl = $('input', node).val();
                console.log("noControl: " + noControl);
            }

            if(colIdx > 2){ 
                var node = this.node();
                calif = $('input', node).val();
                console.log("calif: " + calif);
            }

            if(calif > 1 && calif < 70){
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'warning',
                    title: 'CALIFICACION INCORRECTA',
                    html: '<p>La calificacion del No. Control: <b>' + noControl + '</b> debe de ser 0 o estar entre 70 y 100</p>',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    allowEnterKey: false,
                    confirmButtonText: 'ENTENDIDO', 
                    confirmButtonColor: '#0050E4',
                });

                return false;
            } else {
                enviar('calificaciones_parciales_bd.php', 'calificaciones');
            } 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: cambia esto **if(calif > 1 && calif < 70)** por esto **if((calif > 1) && (calif < 70))**

Answer (score 1):

El return que tienes dentro del if no va a detener la validacion de todas las rows que le quedan, solo detendrá la row actual.

Para que no te salte la funcion `enviar()` cuando has encontrado un error, puedes probar algo así:

```
function validaCalificacion(){
    //... lo que quieras
    let vamosBien = true;

    table.rows().every( function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        table.cells($(this), $('td')).every(function (rowIdx, colIdx){  
            let calif;            

            if(vamosBien){
               // tus ifs y tus cosas aquí
                if(calif > 1 && calif < 70){
                   // tu alert y tus cosas
                   vamosBien = false;
                }else {
                    enviar('calificaciones_parciales_bd.php', 'calificaciones');
                } 
         }
         // ...            

}
```

Dime que tal te funciona.

Comment: Seguí tu consejo, pero no funcionó. Sí me valida la calificación y aparece el alert pero la función enviar() se ejecuta inmediatamente después.

Comment: he rectificado la declaración del vamosBien para el inicio de la funcion. Ahora si te tiene que funcionar bine. Si te salta el alert se paraliza todo. Dime que tal funciona la cosa. Un saludo

Comment: También ya lo intenté y sigue sin funcionar mi estimado. Probé metiendo el código al ChatGPT y me dio la explicación de lo que hace el código, y según esto sí tendría qie funcionar. No entiendo por qué no lo hace.

Comment: Si entra en el condicional **if** luego no entra en el **else** eso es cierto el 100% de los casos. Tu funcion vas iterando para cada **row**. Lo cual si una row falla, puede ser que la siguiente haga saltar la funcion del Else. Pero si has implementado el booleano **vamosBien** tal y como te he dicho, eso tampoco es posible. Así que si dices que aún así te llama a la funcion de dentro del **else** la única posibilidad és que estés llamando dos veces la funcion **validaCalificacion** en algún lugar de tu codigo. Edita y muestra como llamas esta funcion y lo miramos. Un saludo.

Comment: Compañero, ya funcionó, lo que hice fue meter el **if** que valida la calificaciń dentro del **if** que evalua el **colIdx > 2** y con eso se solucionó. Agradezco mucho tu apoyo, responderé a mi pregunta con el código que ya funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Después de revisar detenidamente mi problema intenté meter el **if** que valida la calificación dentro del **if** que evalua las columnas y con esto se solucionó. Comparto el código de cómo quedó al final.

```
function validaCalificacion(){
    var table = $('#tabla_calificaciones').DataTable();
    let vamosBien = true;

    table.rows().every( function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        table.cells($(this), $('td')).every(function (rowIdx, colIdx){  
            let calif;

            if(colIdx === 1){ 
                var node = this.node();
                noControl = $('input', node).val();
                console.log("noControl: " + noControl);
            }

            if(colIdx > 2){ 
                var node = this.node();
                calif = $('input', node).val();
                console.log("noControl: " + noControl + " calif: " + calif);

                if(calif > 1 && calif < 70){
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'warning',
                        title: 'CALIFICACION INCORRECTA',
                        html: '<p>La calificacion del No. Control: <b>' + noControl + '</b> debe de ser 0 o estar entre 70 y 100</p>',
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        allowEnterKey: false,
                        confirmButtonText: 'ENTENDIDO',  
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0050E4',
                    }); 

                    vamosBien = false;
                } 
            }
        });
    });

    if(vamosBien != false){
        enviar('calificaciones_parciales_bd.php', 'calificaciones');
    } 
}
```